# Forms : add new item in select option value list from database

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with a list populated by items taken from a table of database :

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic-0">Problem</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="type" name="type" class="input-xlarge">
        <option value="defaut"></option> 
         <?php
         while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
        echo utf8_encode ("<option>".$data[type]."</option>"); 
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

That works well, but I would like to add the option for the user to add an item to the select component if their desired response isn't there by default. If they add a select option it would be saved to the table so it would show up in future page loads. How could I do this? Thank you for the help!

Comment: really confusing what you want. can you explain little bit more or if possible to add example.

Comment: Sorry.. I made an edit (thanks @Sam..)

Comment: You can use ajax for save new options & fetch options from db using ajax .

Comment: Yes, my first thought was using Ajax.. but I didn't manage to do it.. could you post some snippet please ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little javascript will do:

```
var select = document.getElementById('#type');
option = //Get your data you want to add and put it between two <option> tags
select.appendChild(option);
```

If you want that on a button click, just put the code above inside a function, and have the button call that function on the click.